# Can bash omit backupfiles when completing commands?

Tags: bash, path, executable, bash-completion

When completing commands, executables in $PATH and all, I would like to omit files named #foo# and bar~. I don't mind having these backup-files laying around, but prefer not to see them when completing commands. Do I need to somehow write a bash-completer function for that?

It's completion of the first word at the prompt I am talking about;

```
bash# auda[TAB]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set suffixes to ignore using the [FIGNORE](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#index-FIGNORE-192) variable:

```
export FIGNORE='~:#'
```

List the suffixes to be ignored, separated by colons.

For the full gory details see [*Programmable Completion*](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) in the Bash Reference Manual.